# How to make CloudWatch logs agent running properly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

What I'm trying to do is to monitor log file through CloudWatch logs agent.

I have installed CloudWatch to my EC2 Linux Instance (EC2 Instance has Instance profile and IAM Role that are connected). 
The installation was successful, but when I'm using `sudo service awslogs status`
I'm having this status massage *dead but pid file exists*.

In my error log file ( /var/log/awslogs.log) I have only this line that repeats over and over again - 'AccessKeyId'.

How can I fix Cloud Watch logs agent and make it to work?

Answer (score 2):

This means that your AWS Logs agent requires your AWS Access Key/Secret. This can be provided in /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf in following format:

```
[plugins]
cwlogs = cwlogs
[default]
region = YOUR_INSTANCE_REGION (e.g. us-east-1)
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Restart the service after making this change:

```
sudo service awslogs restart
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I have found the reason. And the reason was in IAM Role permission. And if you are using IAM role you don't need to specify account credentials. But thenk you for your time and answer!